A María nunca se le conoció negro con el que anduviera entretenida
No entiendo esta frase:

A María nunca se le conoció negro con el que anduviera entretenida

(de Las hijas de la criada / Sonsoles Ónega p.50)
¿Alguien me la puede explicar?

De acuerdo con el lugar donde esté escrito, "negro" puede ser un hombre de color o un hombre cualquiera.
La oración tiene una clara alusión sexual:

A María nunca se le conoció negro con el que anduviera entretenida.

Puede ser que María fuera muy exigente y ningún hombre (negro) conseguía satisfacerla, o María se aburría muy pronto de sus pretendientes.
Si la duda radica en el verbo "conocer", el pronominal "conocérsele (a alguien algo/alguien)" significa "conocer algo/alguien propio de esa persona".

A Juan no se le conocen vicios = Nadie conoce vicios de Juan / Nadie sabe que Juan tenga vicios

A María no se le conoce novio = Nadie conoce un novio de María / Nadie sabe que María tenga novio


"Andar entretenido con alguien" quiere decir "estar entusiasmado/divertido con alguien".

Estoy de acuerdo con lo expuesto arriba. Lo que me resulta algo extraño es esa equiparación de "negro" y "hombre" en la Galicia de principios del siglo XX que es donde parece transcurrir la novela. Pocos (ninguno?) negros había ahí.

@RubioRic los gallegos emigraron muchísimo a América (Viví en Galicia), no me sorprendería que para esas fechas ya anduvieran con frases del otro lado del charco. Eso de "Mi Negro" viene de varios países entre ellos Cuba, Colombia, Venezuela y otros...

@OCHOA Sí, esa frase parece más propia de esos países. No he leído la novela, desconozco el contexto planteado por la autora, la verdad. Puede que sea eso que indicas. Solo lo apuntaba como curiosidad.
